# Rasa installation issue : after creating virtual environment when I have tried pip install rasa..the following error occurs

Tags: rasa

### ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\Hritam\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Hritam\venv\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Hritam\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuy_g_x1w'
cwd: C:\Users\Hritam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f7h2dcn3\ujson
Complete output (5 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'ujson' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
Failed to build ujson
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve ?

Comment: Welcome to SO - it is encouraged that you post what you tried along with the command that lead to the error message, and what you understand of it so far. You'll be much more likely to get (good) answers

Answer (score 0):

In general you may want to take care installing the Rasa dependencies on a windows machine. There's some C++ dependencies that might mess things up. There's guides online that should help you though. I'll list them here for future reference of other folks who experience installation issues.

- [windows 10 install](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ewIABo0OkU)
- [ubuntu install](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXiYJM2vGJk)
- [MacOS install](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqzsE70Rvr0)